# How to fix a bump over central main beam and level floor?

Tags: floor, structural, joists, beam, old-house

I reside in a 1950s-era bungalow. In its basement lies a wood beam, connecting and upholding the joists (2x10) through a 2x4 ledger that's been nailed in place. The structural walls on the main floor slightly diverge from the basement's central beam, resting instead upon the joists. Notably, there's a discernible elevation (bump) in the hallway floor directly above this central basement beam, spanning the entire length of the house.

The cause of this elevation is a roughly 2x2 piece of wood placed atop the beam, bridging the gap between adjacent joists. Furthermore, a height disparity of approximately 1.5 inches exists between the house's outer walls (which are taller) and its central region where the beam is positioned.
The joists are secured to this central beam by four diagonal nails each. The beam in question is a singular 8 x 12 x 40 ft piece, reinforced along the house's length by three wooden columns.

Should I try to straighten the beam, or perhaps, the joists or other action?
The beam, wood on top, joist and 2x4 ledger are visible from this picture:

https://imgur.com/8VjXHHI

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Not sure if such a structural change is DIY, or needs professional support (no pun intended).

Comment: it sounds to me like the beam is the only thing doing its job as the rest of the house sags around it,